Handle js 'window.resizeTo' in Microsoft WebView2
I am currently developing a Win32 C++ based WebView2 program.
I am writing this post because I have a question regarding WebView2.
I know that Webview2 API provides a callback that can be handled when calling window.open.
(add_NewWindowRequested and ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventHandler)
By setting put_Handled(true) in ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs obtained within the callback, or using put_NewWindow, you can open the WebView2 window that you newly create.
Alternatively, I understand that if the request is not handled, a popup created by the Edge engine itself will be displayed.
(In this case, if you enter window.chrome.webview into that window through developer tools, it will be displayed as undefined.)
Question)
About this question, popups generated by the Edge engine (NewWindowRequested not handled) window.resizeTo works fine.
window.resizeTo does not work on newly created WebView2 windows via NewWindowRequested.
Q1) Is there a way to handle that event?
(Even if I checked with Spy++, no special events(window messsge) are received in the WebView 2 popup I created.)
(It seems that windows created in the Edge engine internally receive events through some means and adjust the window through SetWindowPos.)
Q2) According to Mozilla MDN, for window.resizeTo to work, the window must be opened as a popup(not tab) and as window.open. Is the window opened with NewWindowRequested recognized as a 'tab'? In this case, is resizeTo not working due to policy?
If there is no other way, try to handle resize natively by calling postMessage in javascript.I've been struggling for a long time to find a solution to this problem.
help :(
For pop-ups that open from the Edge engine itself
(e.g. if NewWindowRequested is not handled in WebView2 or window.open is done in Edge browser developer tools) Events like WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING are raised.
If a pop-up is opened by directly handling NewWindowRequested in WebView2, no special window event occurs.

Just tested, app created windows with WebView2 receive WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

Are you referring to the case where a new WebView2 object and a window object are created, and the newly created WebView2 object is put into put_NewWindow inside ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventHandler?
(I am not from an English-speaking country, so I am using a translator, so the sentences may be inaccurate)

Yes, a new window is created and new CoreWebView2 is created environment->CreateCoreWebView2Controller() in a ICoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventHandler and put_NewWindow is set in a ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2ControllerCompletedHandler.

When I call SetWindowPos or drag the edge of a newly created WebView 2 window, the WebView 2 window will naturally receive WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING or WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED. What I'm curious about is whether if I open the F12 developer tools targeting that window and call window.resizeTo, the WebView 2 window receives the above message or not. I tested again, but it doesn't seem to be receiving properly. Can you share your testing sequence or method?
